# Basis of an orthogonal vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $u=(1, 2, ..., n)$ and $v=(n, ..., 2, 1)$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $H$ be the subspace of all vectors that orthogonal to these two above vectors. The question is  to find the dimension of $H$ and give an example of its basis.

I see that $u$ and $v$ are two linear independence vectors, so the orthogonal complement of $H$ has dimension $2$. Therefore $H$ has dimension $n-2$.

Now, I turn to find a basis for $H$. Suppose $x=(x_1,..., x_n)$ is a vector in $H$.

Hence the cross products $\langle x, u\rangle=\langle x, v\rangle=0$.

Thus $x_1+2x_2+...+nx_n=0$ and $nx_1+...+2x_{n-1}+x_n=0$.

Therefore $x_1+...+x_n=0$.

Combining the three formulas above, I see that $x_{n-1}=-(n-1)x_1-(n-2)x_2-...-2x_{n-2}$ and $x_{n}=(n-2)x_1+(n-3)x_2+...+x_{n-2}$.

and we can see that here is a basis for $H$

$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
...\\
0\\
-(n-1)\\
n-2
\end{array}
\right) $ , $\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
0\\
...\\
0\\
-(n-2)\\
n-3
\end{array}
\right) $ , ...., $\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
...\\
0\\
1\\
-2\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right) $

I think that my solution is too complicated.

My question is: Is there any easier way to find a basis for $H$?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $$V:= \operatorname{span} \{u,v\},$$ then

$$\mathbb{R}^n = V \oplus H = V \oplus V^\perp$$

Comment: Yes, I did use that to find out the dimension of $H$. My problem is is there any easier way to find a basis for $H$?